# Why do constellations exist?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

I was trying to understand a ramified coverings of a puntured sphere and came to the book "Graphs on Surfaces and Their Applications" S. Lando, A. Zvonkin. In the first chapter they define a *constellation* as

> A sequence $[ g_1, g_2, ...,g_k ]$, where $g_i \in S_n$, is called a constellation (or a $k$-constellation) if the following two properties
> are satisfied:
>
> - the group $G = \langle g_1, g_2,...,g_k \rangle$ acts transitively on the set of $n$ points
> - the product of $g_i$ is the identity permutation: $g_1g_2...g_k = id$

So there is my question: if $G$ acts transitively on set of $n$ points, why does it not equal to $S_n$?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading it, the question is really just about group actions and not about constellations in particular. Anyway, every group $G$ acts transitively on a collection of $|G|$ objects, namely, on $G$ itself by left multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transitive action just means that any point can go to any other point. This can happen when $G$ is much smaller than $S_n$, for example, if $G$ is a group of order $n$ generated by the $n$-cycle $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$. If $G=S_n$ then all the points $\{1,2,\ldots\,n\}$ can go to any permutation of the $n$ points, which is a much stronger condition than transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, every subgroup $G$ of $S_n$, all whose pointwise stabilizers have order $a$ such that $n=\frac{|G|}{a}$, acts transitively on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. @Ted's answer provides a minimal example, with $|G|=n$ and $a=1$.